# Windows 10 ISO content looks odd ("." directory)

Tags: windows, dot-files, file-browser

I've downloaded Windows 10 Disc Image from [microsoft.com](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) recently. I mounted it using Archive Mounter in Ubuntu. And I saw just a hidden folder "." and an empty "README.TXT" file in the root.

[image: Files screenshot]

`ls -aR` result is

```
.:
.  .  ..  README.TXT
```

The disk content looks strange to me, I have not seen this before, and I think it may be some kind of protection from file browsing. Because when I try to enter "." directory I remain in the same directory. I know that "." has a special meaning: [What do “.” and “..” mean when in a folder?](https://askubuntu.com/q/54900/519758) - and this's probably a reason why I can't enter "." directory.

- Is it really a trick from MS to hide disk internals?
- Do you know any anti-trick? =)

---

SHA1: 87b7a45c8fd9f016126230399c7e3a470b2ca1da
SHA256: 3dfbd43a1163ee420464a604cd876ac3070606dd72d4abfa5f6e3f1f4f68d08e
filesize: 4.1 GB

They don't match anything on the internet, but MS MVP [says](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/i-have-downloaded-a-windows-iso-file-what-are-the/22235a8a-19d9-4700-9bfc-3d051d9ee046):

> The checksums are all over the place, you are not gonna find one thats the same to match what you downloaded.

---

UPD:

I've redownloaded the disk image and now its size is 4.7 GB and its checksum matches the one provided by [@Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/9785/ignacio-vazquez-abrams). The above question is still actual: when the image is mounted using Archive Mounter its content looks odd, but when it's "burned" to USB I can see installation files and browse freely.

Comment: Did you read the other file?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, README.TXT? It's empty...

Comment: Strange. I downloaded the Windows ISO previously as well, and it shows up as expected. Is there a checksum you can verify against?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams please, see the edited question

Comment: If your checksum doesn't match *anything* (I checked mine [Win10_1709_English_x64.iso, 1ad928cfef439f6aa4044ddc3a96b0b6830bdd0f] and got a large number of matches) then I would suspect that the image is broken.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thank you! I'm going to redownload the image then.